# How to use placeholder in Azure Storage Blob?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'll be performing some calls to blobs in Azure Storage. There will be some cases where I'll be calling blobs that don't exist.

My question is do I need to check on each call if the blob exists using

```
public static bool BlobExistsOnCloud(CloudBlobClient client, 
    string containerName, string key)
{
     return client.GetContainerReference(containerName)
                  .GetBlockBlobReference(key)
                  .Exists();  
}
```

or can I perform some sort of configuration on the container to show a placeholder in case the specific blob does not exist?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us an example what you expect to happen when a blob doesn't exist?

Comment: Blob storage doesn't have a concept of "placeholder" - if you put something there as a placeholder, it is, itself, a blob.

Comment: I would be expecting to configure the following error message to show a predefined blob. A little like you can do in IIS for 404.
 <Error>
<Code>BlobNotFound</Code>
<Message>
The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:7c905e30-d01e-00a7-57a5-3f5551000000 Time:2018-08-29T14:37:47.9791279Z
</Message>
</Error>

Comment: You can check if they exist in advance but honestly it is just better to try to read it and handle the exception that occurs.